# Promote a major mode kbd to a higher priority than the same ones used by a minor mode

Tags: latex, auctex

I am using emacs to write LaTeX documents with AucTeX and cdlatex. Both of them have the same feature of automatically closing parens and dollar sign symbols. However, AucTeX obviously did a better job implenting that functionality, which is what I prefer to use.

That said, currently it's cdlatex that is doing the job of closing parens, which is very annoying. I tried to turn it off in cdlatex's customization but that just disables the functionality entirely. Is there a way to lift AucTex to a higher priority?

Here's my init:

```lisp
;; this is more on the global side but I have it enabled anyways
(electric-pair-mode 1) ;; automatically close parens, etc.

(setq LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace 1) ;; automatic close tags
;; matching dollar sign
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda () (set (make-local-variable 'TeX-electric-math)(cons "$" "$"))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-cdlatex) ;; enabled in AUCTeX LaTeX mode
;; (setq cdlatex-paired-parens nil)
(setq cdlatex-paired-parens "[{($")
```

**Solution:**
As Stefan suggested below, I got it to work after adding the following lines to my init:

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'cdlatex
    (lambda ()
        (substitute-key-definition 'cdlatex-pbb nil cdlatex-mode-map)
        (substitute-key-definition 'cdlatex-dollar nil cdlatex-mode-map)
     ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you report this problem as a bug.  It also prevents the use of the standard pairing minor mode `electric-pair-mode`.

As for a workaround, you could try

```
(substitute-key-definition 'cdlatex-pbb nil cdlatex-mode-map)
(substitute-key-definition 'cdlatex-dollar nil cdlatex-mode-map)
```

Comment: It worked! I did not realize that it a keybinding issue.

Comment: @graduagrey: you might want to update the title of your question accordingly?

Comment: done! Thanks so much for your help.